# Create relational tables or store serialized data in a column?

Tags: php, sql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a `users` table with this structure:

```
    user_id | name | email | mobile
```

And another table called `products` with this structure:

```
   product_id | name | price
```

now I want to add **wish list** to my project, so that a `user` can add some `products` into his wish list (with his favorite categories. Exmaple: add a wish list category called `my favorite clothes` and add product_id = 55 to that category)!

Now I have **2 options**:

**1.** Add another colum to users table called `user_wish_list` and then store serialized data in that column like below:

```
$user_wish_list = [
    'user_category_1' => ['product_id_1', 'product_id_2', ....] ;
];
```

and store  `serialize($user_wish_list)` in `user_wish_list`  column.

**2.** create 2 tables as below:

tabe: *wish_list_categories*

```
user_id | category_id (PK) | category_title
```

and

tabe: *wish_list_items*

```
category_id (FK) | item_id | product_id (FK)
```

and finally create a relation between these tables (By [SQL join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp))

which option is better? I personally think the **second** one! 
one of the reasons for my choice is that I can access to data with pure SQL query
 like below (I do not have to process data after fetching from database by using `unserialize()` ):

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.name, wish_list_categories.category_id, 
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON users.user_id = wish_list_categories.category_id
```

But what about other advantages?

Or let me ask a more general question: when we exactly use **relational tables** instead of use column? (consider `one-to-one` relationship)

Comment: Can they?  Yes.  Should they?  No.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.

Answer (score 1):

Use tables.  In general, don't store structured data in individual SQL values.  Let the tables and foreign keys produce the structure you need.

Answer (score 0):

your tables should be like:

1- users table:

```
user_id|user_name|Email|price
```

2- products table:

```
product_id|product_name|category_id|price
```

3- products_category

```
category_id|category_name
```

4- user_wish_list table:

```
user_id|product_id
```